# Incorret Date value passed to Access VBA Function

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access

I am trying to calculate a leave balance depending on Employees' contract type and status. The function is simple and the formula works fine but I can't get the function to retrieve the Termination Date from the Query. Termination Date comes with the value of 00:00:00 while Terminated is TRUE. 
I have tried Dlookup function to collect the data but no luck, I guess i am under the famous date curse of Access. 
Thanks in advance.

My query look like this: 
[image]
[qryLeaveBalance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAFfs.png)

And My function:

```
Public Function LeaveBalanceCalc(EmployeeType As String, HiredDate As Date, Terminated As Boolean, Optional TerminatedDate As Date) As Double


Dim EarningRate As Double
Dim FirstMonthEarning As Double
Dim LastMonthEarning As Double
Dim enddate As Date

'First to determine the earning rate for the employee
    Select Case EmployeeType
        Case Is = "International"
            EarningRate = 4
        Case Else
            EarningRate = 1.25
    End Select

    enddate = Now()

    If Terminated = True Then

     enddate = TerminatedDate

    End If

            FirstMonthEarning = (DateDiff("d", HiredDate, LastOfMonth(HiredDate)) + 1) * (EarningRate / (DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(HiredDate), LastOfMonth(HiredDate)) + 1))

            LastMonthEarning = (DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(enddate), enddate) + 1) * (EarningRate / (DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(enddate), LastOfMonth(enddate)) + 1))

            LeaveBalanceCalc = FormatNumber((DateDiff("m", HiredDate, enddate) - 2) * EarningRate + FirstMonthEarning + LastMonthEarning, 2)

End Function
```

Hi All,

Little more background to my problem. The function is to calculate the leave days earned by employees' longevity. My goal is to add a calculated column to a query, named **Balance** please see the above query, that has Employee's information.

I have tried some other ways; for example below code for the function calculates (Correctly), only the **Terminated** Employees and all others are calculated by **0** date instead of **Now()**. Below alternative function uses **TerminatedDate** itself to determine and calculate the **Balance**. If the **TerminatedDate** is Nz set to be **Now()** but retuns with 00:00:00 date.
Below is the alternative function;

```
Public Function LeaveBalanceCalc(EmployeeType As String, HiredDate As Date, TerminatedDate As Date) As Double

    '................................................................................................................................
    'Name:   LeaveBalanceCalc
    'Inputs: EmployeeType as string
    '        HiredDate as date
    '        TerminatedDate as date
    'Return: as Double
    'Date:   07/02/2020
    'Comment:This function is to calculate the earned leave days by longevity
    '.................................................................................................................................


    Dim EarningRate As Double
    Dim FirstMonthEarning As Double
    Dim LastMonthEarning As Double

    'First we need to determine the earning rate for the employee
        Select Case EmployeeType
            Case Is = "International"
                EarningRate = 4
            Case Else
                EarningRate = 1.25
        End Select


        If Nz(TerminatedDate) Then

            TerminatedDate = Now()

        End If

                FirstMonthEarning = (DateDiff("d", HiredDate, FirstOfMonth(HiredDate)) + 1) * (EarningRate / DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(HiredDate), LastOfMonth(HiredDate)))
                LastMonthEarning = (DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(TerminatedDate), TerminatedDate) + 1) * (EarningRate / (DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(TerminatedDate), LastOfMonth(TerminatedDate)) + 1))
                LeaveBalanceCalc = ((DateDiff("m", HiredDate, TerminatedDate)) * EarningRate) + FirstMonthEarning + LastMonthEarning

    End Function
```

I would be happy if I can make eihter function to work.

Comment: I don't know what the famous Access date curse is, but your enddate is commented out in the "Case Is = True" block, but you are referencing it

Comment: yes I did comment it out from my code but I used the TerminatedDate in the formula instead. When I first wrote "TRUE" case had the same formula as "False". This was just a hopeless try. The curse is the confusion between US date and UK date format in access VBA and query.

Comment: LeaveBalanceCalc uses enddate.  Do you even need to use DateSerial?  Looks like you can just use the date variable you already have.

Comment: I have amended the code, as you suggested. Now it uses the enddate for both. You are right, I can change the dateserial in the formula for enddate. Formula copied from the one of the earlier versions, so that is why the dateserial is still there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but please also amend the title of your question. It has zero use for any future readers.

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman, I would glad to change it but I am new to VBA and I can't figure out possible causes. If you have any suggestion I will take your advice on the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S/O.  Although I am don't program with VB/Access, I can provide this much...

A Date is a Date is a Date... Why keep trying to convert to DateSerial().  The 'Date' data type doesn't care about the visual output presentation based on international preferences of month/day vs day/month, it is stored in a date format.  The date is what it is.

That said, I would simplify as follows (again, not being a VB programmer, adjust syntax where needed).  You have already declared the variable "enddate" as a date field, why ask for the DateSerial() of it.  Its already a date, just take the Now() value.  After that, if there IS a terminated date provide, pull that into the end date to take its place.  Now you KNOW you are getting the correct date for computation purposes.

```
' no matter what, default the end date to whatever now is
enddate = Now()

' if terminated, use this to supersede
If Terminated = True
  enddate = TerminatedDate
End If
```

Now, after testing in Excel with Dates and DateDiff(), you don't need to strip the granular hours/minutes for the calculations that will be ignored when testing for "d"ay (or any other part as well)

```
a DateDiff() by day of 
ex : "2020-02-10 12:00:00AM" and "2020-02-11 12:00:00AM" will result in 1 DAY
AND: "2020-02-10 12:00:00AM" and "2020-02-11 11:47:32PM" will result in 1 DAY
AND: "2020-02-11 11:47:32PM" and "2020-02-12 12:00:00AM" and will result in 1 DAY
(even though it is only just over 12 minutes away, it still considers it as 1 day)
```

Then, you have 2 dates for your computations... endDate (via Now(), or the 
terminated) and the Hired Date.  Finish computations

```
FirstMonthEarning = (DateDiff("d", HiredDate, LastOfMonth(HiredDate)) + 1) * (EarningRate / (DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(HiredDate), LastOfMonth(HiredDate)) + 1))

LastMonthEarning = (DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(enddate), enddate) + 1) * (EarningRate / (DateDiff("d", FirstOfMonth(enddate), LastOfMonth(enddate)) + 1))

LeaveBalanceCalc = FormatNumber(((DateDiff("m", HiredDate, enddate ) - 2) * EarningRate) + FirstMonthEarning + LastMonthEarning, 2)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Now I have a clean code but still Terminated Date passes the function as 00:00:00

Comment: @OpsMan, then I would go one step prior... how and where are you getting that from... Is it from a query or other?  If so, edit your ORIGINAL post, go to the bottom and post the additional information.  Don't try to provide more detail like that in a comment...